# How to restore Vista from a corrupted install of Xubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows-vista, partition-recovery

On my laptop, I've decided to get Xubuntu. During the process, my laptop overheated and shutdown during the installation process. As I turn it back on, it has GRUB, not allowing me to go on Xubuntu or my original OS, Windows Vista. I read somewhere that you need to place back the installation CD. I do so, and it comes up with these options:

- Microsoft System Restore
- File backup program
- System recovery
- Factory Reset

Which option would work best for me? In addition, how can I remove GRUB and the corrupted Xubuntu partition from my computer in the process? Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything on your Vista partition not backed up? (This can help with suggestions, for example: factory reset isn't a possible solution if you have important files). Also, I've done this (Vista+Xubuntu on laptop), it works great. No matter what the outcome, if your lappy is overheating trying to install Xubuntu, it may have some underlying hardware issues to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but Xubuntu was installing when it overheated and turned off. This makes it impossible for Xubuntu to boot because it's corrupted and Vista to boot possibly because of a corrupted grub installation.