# Why is Windows claiming Vista is counterfeit after installing updates?

Tags: windows-vista, updates, system-recovery

We've purchased a Compaq Presario CQ60 Notebook PC from a local Wal-Mart a few years ago. Upon our first boot, we were asked to create recovery discs of Windows Vista because the manufacturer did not provide installation discs.

Recently, Xubuntu was installed and corrupted the system ([post here](https://superuser.com/questions/542562/how-to-restore-vista-from-a-corrupted-install-of-xubuntu)). Our only option to remove it completely is to make a factory reset from the recovery discs. Since the discs were created a few years ago, a massive amount of updates showed up. On our first attempt to do all of those updates at once, the result was a warning from Windows saying that our Windows Vista OS was counterfeit. We know that we don't have a counterfeit OS because we have a Genuine Windows Vista Home Basic Certificate of Authenticity. What should we do and how do we prevent this problem from occurring again?

Thanks!

Comment: See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931573) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940315) and follow the steps mentioned.

Comment: You will thank yourself if you upgrade to Windows 7 or Windows 8. Don't bother with Vista.

Comment: Could the corrupted Xubuntu install have somehow screwed with your OEM licensing? If none of the above solutions help, try calling Microsoft and telling them what happened - generally it's not too hard to get them to activate software if your story sounds believable enough (and you have to original license key that came with your machine)

Comment: Yea, you're right. I contacted them during the event, and I got a new key. With that new key, everything worked out in the end :)